# Nuget configuration error after migrating DotNetCore from VS2015 to VS2017

Tags: migration, nuget, .net-core

After migrating A DotNetCore application from VS2015 to VS2017, I am getting a Reference error when I try to run the application.

If I try to manage my nuget packages I get an 'nuget configuration is invalid' error. In the output window i see lots of "

> TF10121: The path '///[NuGetDependency;;;;]' is not found or not
>   supported. Type or select a different path.

"

I tried searching the internet but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I am having this same error, except with a brand new project.  All patches are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I faced this issue, restarting VS 2017 helped. Make sure you have the latest updates installed for VS 2017.